# 1d CNN audio in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I want to try to implement the neural network architecture of the attached image: [1DCNN_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCcsl.png)

Consider that I've got a dataset X which is `(N_signals, 1500, 40)` where 40 is the number of features where I want to do the 1d convolution on.
My Y is `(N_signals, 1500, 2)` and I'm working with `keras`.
Every 1d convolution needs to take one feature vector like in this picture:[1DCNN_convolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iet2.png)

So it has to take one chunk of the 1500 timesamples, pass it through the 1d convolutional layer (sliding along time-axis) then feed all the output features to the LSTM layer.

I tried to implement the first convolutional part with this code but I'm not sure what it's doing, I can't understand how it can take in one chunk at a time (maybe I need to preprocess my input data before?):

```
input_shape = (None, 40)
model_input = Input(input_shape, name = 'input')
layer = model_input
convs = []
for i in range(n_chunks):
    conv = Conv1D(filters = 40,
                  kernel_size = 10,
                  padding = 'valid',
                  activation = 'relu')(layer)
    conv = BatchNormalization(axis = 2)(conv)
    pool = MaxPooling1D(40)(conv)
    pool = Dropout(0.3)(pool)
    convs.append(pool)
out = Merge(mode = 'concat')(convs)

conv_model = Model(input = layer, output = out)
```

Any advice? Thank you very much

Comment: Hmm... Someone is trying to do the "Rare Sound Event Detection" network from cochlear.ai. How did it work?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much, I modified my code in this way:

```
input_shape = (1500,40)                             
model_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input')                    
layer = model_input                                                     
layer = Conv1D(filters=40,
               kernel_size=10,
               padding='valid',
               activation='relu')(layer)
layer = BatchNormalization(axis=2)(layer)                           
layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=40,
                     padding='same')(layer)                             
layer = Dropout(self.params.drop_rate)(layer)                           
layer = LSTM(40, return_sequences=True,
             activation=self.params.lstm_activation)(layer)         
layer = Dropout(self.params.lstm_dropout)(layer)
layer = Dense(40, activation = 'relu')(layer)
layer = BatchNormalization(axis = 2)(layer)                
model_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(2,
                                     activation='sigmoid'))(layer)
```

I was actually thinking that maybe I have to permute my axes in order to make maxpooling layer work on my 40 mel feature axis...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform an individual 1D convolution over the 40 feature channels you should add a dimension to your input:

```
(1500,40,1)
```

if you perform 1D convolution on a input with shape

```
(1500,40)
```

the filters are applied on the time dimension and the pictures you posted indicate that this is not what you want to do.

Comment: The problem is that the Conv1D layer in keras needs a tensor of shape (batch_size, steps, input_dim) and I have a tensor with (batch_size, time_dim, feature_dim), how can I feed it through the 1D layer?

Comment: checkout the keras Reshape layer